# How can I link to a tabbed screen from a dashboard button and maintain navigation history in Ionic?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with the initial view being a dashboard containing several buttons which link to tabbed screens. Using Ionic framework, I've linked to the tabbed screens using:

```
ui-sref="tab.tab1"
```

The problem with this is the navigation history doesn't seem to work unless I go to that screen using the actual tab bar link. The Back button does not display when I link to the screen from the dashboard but it does display when I navigate to a different tab then back to the same tab. By linking to the tabbed screen from outside of the tab bar, it seems like the navigation history isn't activated unless I actually use the tab bar.

I've tried using:

```
href="#/tab/tab1"
```

like tabs.html does but the link doesn't redirect to the relevant screen.

Is it possible to link to a tabbed page from a dashboard button while using the navigation history for tabbed screens?

I'm using the tabbed app template created by Ionic as the basis for the app.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you need any further help let me know.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Ffwxv/)

**JS**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "contact.html"
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to manually add the button.
In your view add this:

```
<ion-view title="Friends">
 //ADD BACK BUTTON
 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
  <button ng-click="goBack()" class="button button-icon icon ion-arrow-left-c">
 </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="friend in friends" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/friend/{{friend.id}}">
        {{friend.name}}
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And in your controller:

```
.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, Friends,$ionicNavBarDelegate) {
  //GO BACK
  $scope.goBack = function()
    {
      console.log('back');
      $ionicNavBarDelegate.back();
    };
    $scope.friends = Friends.all();
})
```